# org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher: Could not find action or result Error

Tags: struts2

i tried to code the following simple struts but encounter this error during run time.

```
[org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] Could not find action or result: 
No result defined for action com.peter.action.LoginAction and result success
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"  
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>  
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>  
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">  
<html>  
  <body>  
    <h2>Hello Struts</h2>  

    <s:form action="login" >  
      <s:textfield name="username" label="Username:" />  
      <s:password name="password" label="Password:"/>  
      <s:submit />  
    </s:form>  
  </body>  
</html>
```

LoginAction.java

```
package com.peter.action;

import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.ResultPath;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Result;
import org.apache.struts2.convention.annotation.Action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

@ResultPath("/")
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    @Override
    @Action(value = "login", results = 
        {@Result(name="success", location="welcome.jsp")})
    public String execute() {
        return SUCCESS;
    }

    // Getters and setters for username, password    
}
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>Struts</display-name>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Struts_Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>actionPackages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.peter.action</param-value> 
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Struts_Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Besides the runtime error, there is deployment error which is

> ERROR [com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder] (MSC service
>   thread 1-2) Unable to read class
>   [WEB-INF.classes.com.peter.action.LoginAction]: Could not load
>   WEB-INF/classes/com/peter/action/LoginAction.class - [unknown
>   location]     at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.finder.ClassFinder.readClassDef(ClassFinder.java:785)
>   [xwork-core-2.3.1.2.jar:2.3.1.2]

AFAIK, the scanning methodology of struts will scan the default packages named struts2 for any annotated class but i have instructed struts2 to scan in com.peter.action using init-param but still unable to find the class. It is pretty weird.

Comment: It says it can't read the class-is it deployed?

Comment: Of course check to see if there class is there. In the future add the struts2-config-browser jar and then go to /config-browser/index and see what it tells you. Also your statement about package scanning applies only if the struts2-conventions plugin is present (I think it should be used for most projects, personally all projects).

Comment: The LoginAction.class is in the jboss deployment folder. What is the use of struts2-config-browser. I've included the struts2-convention-plugin into classpath. Anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when upgrading to Struts 2.3.8, except instead of the errant class packages starting with `WEB-INF.*` it started with the name of the WAR file (denoted as `WarFileName`).  I solved it by adding the following line to `struts.xml`:

```
<constant name="struts.convention.exclude.packages" value="org.apache.struts.*,org.apache.struts2.*,org.springframework.web.struts.*,org.springframework.web.struts2.*,org.hibernate.*,WarFileName.*"/>
```

Everything but `WarFileName.*` is a default, so I included those as well.  I hope this helps someone.